# calculating ip checksum gives very strange values. Is it addition of all words in iphdr and taking complement of it. What am I missing?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, ip, checksum

So this function so far simply do addition of each word in struct iphdr object after setting 0 to checksum and do the complement. But there is something wrong, with this as what my received ip packets cheksum field is entirely different. what I calculate is giving me negative value

so this is my checksum function simple does following

```
uint16_t ip_checksum(void* vdata,size_t length) {
    // Cast the data pointer to one that can be indexed.
    char* data=(char*)vdata;    
    uint32_t acc=0;    
    // Handle complete 16-bit blocks.
    for (size_t i=0;i+1<length;i+=2) {
        uint16_t word;
        memcpy(&word,data+i,2);
        acc+=ntohs(word);
        /*if (acc>0xffff) {
            acc-=0xffff;
        }*/
    }
  return (~acc);
}
```

so this loop

```
for (size_t i=0;i+1<length;i+=2) {
            uint16_t word;
            memcpy(&word,data+i,2);
            acc+=ntohs(word);
            /*if (acc>0xffff) {
                acc-=0xffff;
            }*/
        }
```

is simply operating on each 16 bit word of received object pointer and doing addition and storing it in acc variable,

Then I complement it like with `~`

```
return (~acc);
```

so basically that what exactly told on the internet to calculate it if I am correct. But when I do this

```
printf("checksum = %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
    iph->check=0;
    int16_t i=ip_checksum(iph,sizeof(iph)); 
    printf("------------------------------------------>%d\n",(i));
```

it prints entirely different values of checksum in two printf above.
So I like to know what am I doing wrong

Comment: If the size of your data is not a multiple of 2, then doing `memcpy(&word,data+i,2)` is a source of trouble.

Comment: If it is a multiple of 2 (always), then you're better of replacing `i+1<length` with `i<length` (I mean, maybe it does the job, maybe it misses out on the last 2 characters; if I were you, then I'd rather not having to ask myself that question).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I tried this `printf("))))))))))))))))))))))%zu\n",length);` in my checksum function its printing 8 its multiple of 2 what do u mean.

Comment: Finally, `memcpy(&word,data+i,2)` is always done in Little Endian order, while `uint16_t word` is subjected to the endianness of your platform. This means that you'll get different results on different platforms, which makes the behavior of your program not well-defined.

Comment: also, the checksum has little-to-big endian convertion. your first print converts it back, and your second print does not.

Comment: @Effie `also, the checksum has little-to-big endian convertion. your first print converts it back, and your second print does not` I tried convert it back in second printf too still different

Comment: BTW, for `if (acc>0xffff)`, note that you can simply replace your `return ~acc` statement with `return ~(acc&0xffff)`. Which, as you might notice, contains a lot of leading 1s. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb whats the point of this `return ~(acc&0xffff)` can u please explain

Comment: Same point as in your original `return ~acc`, but without the need to subtract `0xffff` inside the loop.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb those lines are commented out

Comment: That's why I wrote 'BTW'. As in "BTW, if you ever intend to unmask that"...

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb just to make sure should I calculate checksum from iphdr as I receive right in read()? I mean I only have to add all words and take compliment. is this correct?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including data that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the desired output. Explain why you have commented out the `0xffff` part when that is a necessary part of the checksum. State whether the length is a number of bytes or a number of words.

Comment: i think here is the correct algorithm: https://www.unix.com/programming/117551-calculate-ip-header-checksum-manually.html

Comment: or here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1071#section-4.1. you are not adding the overflow (carry) correct

Comment: When I restore the commented-out lines (about adjusting by 0xFFFF) and run the code in the question with the sample shown [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ip-header-checksum/), the resulting checksum 0xB1E6, as expected (matches the sample in that web page). If you interpret that as a `uint16_t` and print it with `%d`, it produces 45544. If you interpret it as an `int16_t` and print it, it produces −19992. Perhaps that is what you mean by “entirely different values”? **Show the output you got.**

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: Re “If the size of your data is not a multiple of 2”: The size of the data is a multiple of two bytes.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: Re “`memcpy(&word,data+i,2)` is always done in Little Endian order”: `memcpy` copies bytes; it does not have an endian order. The data is not directly used as `uint16_t`; the `ntohs` converts it from network order to host order. The code is correct in that regard; there is no endianness issue.

Comment: @Effie: Re “your first print converts it back, and your second print does not”: There is no need to convert it back. Once the bytes are converted to host order, as `ntohs` does, they are semantically correct, and we can continue to work with the values as is. When storing the computed checksum back into the checksum field, it would be necessary to convert to network order. But for display to the user, showing the value (not the bytes that represent it) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working function, I previously did this check `if (sum >= 0x10000) {`I dont know why it wasnt working back then. now it words solved

So I like to know does tcp checksum also is same I just want to pass the *tcph to following checksum function.

```
uint16_t csum(const void *data, const int length)
{
    /*  Checksum Algorithm (http://www.microhowto.info/howto/calculate_an_internet_protocol_checksum_in_c.html)
    1. Set the sum to 0,
    2. Pad the data to an even number of bytes,
    3. Reinterpret the data as a sequence of 16-bit unsigned integers that are
        in network byte order,
    4. Calculate the sum of the integers, subtracting 0xffff whenever
        the sum => 0x10000, and
    5. Calculate the bitwise complement of the sum and set it as the checksum.
    */
    printf("[[[[[[[[%d]]]]]]]]\n",length);
    uint16_t *accumalator = (uint16_t *)data;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    /* Take care of the first 16-bit even blocks */
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
        sum += *(accumalator+i);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }

    /* Handle the ending partial block */
    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        accumalator = accumalator+ length/2; /* Point accumalator to the end block */
        uint16_t end_block = 0;
        memcpy(&end_block, accumalator, sizeof(length));
        sum += ntohs(end_block);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }
    /* Return the one's complement of the checksum in network byte order */
    return htons(~sum);
}
```

Comment: it is the same function, but the tcp checksum is calculated over the entire tcp segment, not just the header, and this one can have uneven bytes length.

Comment: quatch that, TCP checksum is calculated over entire tcp segment + pseudoheader, which includes IP addresses

Comment: it is written on page 16 of [rfc793](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793)

Comment: @Effie what this mean `pseudoheader, which includes IP addresses` do u mean I need to do tcp checksum on tcphdr object plus ip.saddr and ip.daddr. please clarify

Comment: link to the standard above, and again, not tcphdr, tcphdr + all the payload

Comment: @Effie so should I calculate tcp checksum as with `tcphdr + all the payload` so for example payload containing simply string hello is this what u meant by `tcphdr +all the payload`? All of payload = hello  string?